# I have questions which no one could solve at the time but I later solved, what should I do with the questions?

Tags: discussion, answers, unanswered-questions

I have questions on SF which I asked some time ago and never chose an answer for. This happened because eventually someone else outside of SF worked it out or I worked it out at a later date / workaround.
I cannot remember what the solution was, but it wasn't any of the answers given.
How should I "complete" the question so as to show it's closed? I can't close the question myself as I don't have enough rep on SF yet.

Thoughts?

Note: I understand I can answer my own question but my point is I cannot remember the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your edit you say you don't remember the answer so just leave the question be. Others may still post a solution, perhaps even a different one, at a later stage which may benefit someone else looking for the same thing. It's even possible you later recall what the solutions was, in which case you can go back, post it and mark it as accepted.

I have a number of questions for which I have not accepted an answer. I fully intend to leave the question open because while some cannot be answered right now (no real solution appears to exist), that may change in the future. Anyone looking for a solution to the same problem may even find value in the comments that have been posted.

In short, unless you see some overwhelming reason to have the question removed from the site, why delete it?

Comment: Thanks, that was the answer I was looking for. I guess I felt some sort of social compliance to have questions "completed"

Answer (score 11):

If you have a solution to your problem, you can post an Answer to the problem and mark it as accepted. You won't get rep for it, but it does show that the problem got an answer. Others will upvote you if it is useful. That's perfectly acceptable.

Comment: Yes, I have done that before. As I said in my question, I cannot remember what the solution / answer to the problem was.

Comment: @Relequestual Another option is to flag-for-mod-attention the post and request closure. Also, I believe you can always delete your own posts.

Comment: @rele I *always* upvote good helpful self-answers, and I am sure others do as well; so rest assured when you do this, you will get recognized for it!

Answer (score 3):

I think you should do nothing, or state you found a solution but forgot it (thus demonstrating the problem *is* solveable).  If you close it and at some point later remember the solution, it will get lost, while otherwise you or others who might stumble upon it might answer it, potentially helping others with the same problem.